# Android Volley- Add to database

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I have implemented a simple register details script in Volley that uses a PHP script that I have built, the first time the code was executed it displayed a permission denied error in logcat. I then added the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`as told by others, however now when I try to register an account no messages at all appear in logcat and data is not added either. I have been looking through previous forum posts and cannot find anything similar to what I am encountering

Code:

```
  public void registerAccountButtonOnClick (View v) {

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, registerURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                parameters.put("FIRST_NAME",firstname.getText().toString());
                parameters.put("LAST_NAME",lastname.getText().toString());
                parameters.put("USER_NAME",username.getText().toString());
                parameters.put("PASSWORD",password.getText().toString());
                return parameters;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(request);


    }
```

PHP:

connection.php

```
<?php

define('hostname', 'localhost');
define('username','root');
define('dbpassword', '');
define('databaseName', 'YouDecide');

$connect = mysqli_connect(hostname,username,dbpassword,databaseName);


?>
```

registerAccount.php

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]== "POST") {

    require 'connection.php';
    createAccount();

}

function createAccount()
{
    global $connect;

    $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];

    $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];

    $username = $_POST["username"];

    $password = $_POST["password"];


    $query = "INSERT INTO User(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,USER_NAME,PASSWORD) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$username','$password')";

    mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    mysqli_close($connect);

}

?>
```

printStackTrace:

```
02-18 03:55:12.370 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:158)
02-18 03:55:12.370 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
02-18 03:55:12.370 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 80) after 2500ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
02-18 03:55:12.370 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223)
02-18 03:55:12.370 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:161)
02-18 03:55:12.370 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
02-18 03:55:12.370 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
02-18 03:55:12.370 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
02-18 03:55:12.370 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
02-18 03:55:12.380 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
02-18 03:55:12.380 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
02-18 03:55:12.380 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:362)
02-18 03:55:12.380 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
02-18 03:55:12.380 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
02-18 03:55:12.380 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
02-18 03:55:12.380 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
02-18 03:55:12.380 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
02-18 03:55:12.380 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
02-18 03:55:12.380 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
02-18 03:55:12.380 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
02-18 03:55:12.380 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:257)
02-18 03:55:12.380 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:227)
02-18 03:55:12.380 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:107)
02-18 03:55:12.380 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97)
02-18 03:55:12.380 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:   ... 1 more
02-18 03:55:12.380 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
02-18 03:55:12.380 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:208)
02-18 03:55:12.380 1569-1569/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:   ... 21 more
```

Thanks for looking :-)

Comment: Didn't downvote, but can you post the php?

Comment: Done, thanks for constructive advice :-)

Comment: Are you sure it's on the Volley side? i.e. will the database actually connect? To be sure try: check your table name is `user` not users, type in the query into phpmyadmin (or whatever you use) and see if the table updates, make sure that android volley has the right url. Personally I don't see any glaring issues on the Android side, but I've only used volley once briefly.

Comment: Yeah the SQL script runs fine in phpMyAdmin, I really don't know what I've done wrong!

Comment: Can you put a `error.printStackTrace();` inside the onErrorResponse? Read out the error, if it is on Volley's part. Also put something like `Toast blah= Toast.makeText(context, response.substring(0, 500), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` in `onResponse`. This will tell you if php is mad because it will spill out the contents of the web document

Comment: Thanks, I have added the Stack Trace in the original post above :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it says `failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 80)`

in your android app, you are using wrong IP in the `registerURL`, replace the **127.0.0.1** or **localhost** with the IP address of the machine running the web-server (apache?) it should be something like `192.168.xxx.yyy`

Comment: It works! One other question though, I went to delete the record I made(it was a test record) and I receive the message "Cannot delete, error in syntax (DELETE WHERE LIMIT 1) is this because of foreign keys?

Comment: i am not sure but the sql looks not right, a general delete qry is like `DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id=10` or `WHERE user_name='Smith'` or without `WHERE` at all `DELETE FROM mytable`, and this will delete all records in `mytable` check this too http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp

Comment: Yeah thank you :-) its weird because it is phpMyAdmin doing it automatically rather than me inputting the query myself..

Comment: a small tip, if you are still fresh or studying, always try to write it yourself, don't just take -as is- codes, just try to have an idea about the code or qry you are running, and how it works ;)

Comment: Definitely - when I tried a DELETE query myself it worked just fine, so will carry on doing it that way!